# Select rows that match multiple rows in related table

Tags: mysql, select

I have three tables:

**item**

```
id   name   etc
--------------------
1    Rex   
2    Fido
3    Geoff
```

**category**

```
id   name
------------
1    Dogs
2    Humans
3    Mammals
```

**category_item**

```
category_id  item_id
--------------------
1            1
3            1
1            2
3            2
2            3
3            3
```

I also have an array of category ids. I would like to count the number of items that are related to ALL of the categories in the array.

For example...

```
Category_ids    Result
----------------------
1,2             0
2,3             1
1,2,3           0
```

Pretty sure I'm gonna kick myself when I figure this one out.

Comment: Hi can you please tell me how Result for category_ids '1,2,3' is  3 because there is not a single item who is in all 3 category..thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try query given below..

```
select count(*) AS Result from (
         SELECT count(item_id) FROM category_item
                             WHERE 
                            category_id in (2 ,3)
                            GROUP by item_id 

                              HAVING count(*) = 2
                             ) AS temp
```

In this query  `put count(*) value equal to total number of category_id for example if you are checking for category_ids 1,2,3 then put having count(*) = 3`. In this query let assume you provide category_id 1 and 2 then it will fetch total number of existence of item_id with

I hope this query will helpful for you.

thanks